# JQuery Check if Checkbox is Checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, validation

I'd like to figure out how to write something like the following to validate single check boxes. There could be just one on the form or many separate ones. The example below doesn't work.

Thank you!

```
// -----------------------------------------------
// CHECK SINGLE CHECKBOX
// -----------------------------------------------
$('.mcCbxRequired').each(function() {
    var mcCbxCheck = $(this);
    if(mcCbxCheck.is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
        // do something here ...
    }
    else{
        alert('not checked');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: When you say the example "doesn't work", is it showing the `alert`?

Comment: Hi, No, nothing happens.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it works. I had to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A couple things:

1. Each applicable checkbox must have the `mcCbxRequired` class. If neither alert shows, the problem must be because your checkbox does not have this class.
2. You are `return`ing `false` in both cases. That doesn't really make sense with validation, so you should change the relevant part of your code to this:

*Code:*

```
    if(mcCbxCheck.is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @user582065 just edited his post right before I edited it. Still should have the `return true;` line though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function()
{
   var checkedBox = $(this);

   // Do whatever you want
});
```

Also, JQuery selectors by Class are slower than by id/by type.